# Query takes 944,319.072 ms

Tags: performance, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

This query takes 944,319.072 ms and returns 27 lines.

```
SELECT
    AP_ATTRIBUTE.stylename,
    AP_BASIC.style,
    AP_ATTRIBUTE.color,
    AP_ATTRIBUTE.size,
    AP_BASIC.ap_sizesequence_id AS apSizesequenceId,
    M_TRANSACTION.movementdate AS MOVEMENTDATE,
    SUM(M_TRANSACTION.MOVEMENTQTY) AS MOVEMENTQTY,
    COALESCE(M_PRODUCTPRICE.pricelist, 999999) AS pricelist,
    M_INOUT.M_INOUT_ID,
    M_INOUT.DOCUMENTNO AS DOCUMENTNO,
    C_BPARTNER.VALUE AS BPNAME,
    '' AS M_MOVEMENTLINE_ID,
    '' AS MOVEMENT,
    '' AS MOVEMENT_DESCRIPTION,
    '' AS M_INVENTORY_ID,
    '' AS M_MOVEMENT_ID,
    '' AS M_PRODUCTIONPLAN_ID,
    '' AS PRODUCTION_PLAN
FROM 
    M_TRANSACTION
    LEFT JOIN 
    AP_ATTRIBUTE ON AP_ATTRIBUTE.M_PRODUCT_ID = M_TRANSACTION.M_PRODUCT_ID
    LEFT JOIN 
    AP_BASIC ON AP_BASIC.AP_BASIC_ID = AP_ATTRIBUTE.AP_BASIC_ID
    LEFT JOIN 
    M_PRODUCTPRICE ON 
        M_TRANSACTION.M_PRODUCT_ID = M_PRODUCTPRICE.M_PRODUCT_ID
        AND M_PRODUCTPRICE.m_pricelist_version_id = '69CBAFD24AB24E3CB9B9A44E282D62EC',
        M_INOUTLINE,
        M_INOUT,
        C_BPARTNER
WHERE 
    M_TRANSACTION.M_INOUTLINE_ID = M_INOUTLINE.M_INOUTLINE_ID
    AND M_INOUTLINE.M_INOUT_ID = M_INOUT.M_INOUT_ID
    AND M_TRANSACTION.M_INOUTLINE_ID IS NOT NULL
    AND M_INOUT.C_BPARTNER_ID = C_BPARTNER.C_BPARTNER_ID
    AND M_TRANSACTION.AD_CLIENT_ID IN (
        '0',
        'FF80818129E99DC80129E9AD546A0708'
        )
    AND M_TRANSACTION.AD_ORG_ID IN (
        '44523886B0E0423584BB0E87133F3EE4',
        '4510F92E007E48B28EE6CEB088A78348',
        '0'
        )
    AND AP_ATTRIBUTE.isActive = 'Y'
    AND 1 = 1
    AND M_TRANSACTION.movementdate >= to_date('2012-12-01')
    AND M_TRANSACTION.movementdate < to_date('2013-01-01')
    AND M_INOUT.M_WAREHOUSE_ID = '50657AE0F49A421A9F10154C8632A726'
    AND M_INOUT.ISSOTRX = 'N'
GROUP BY
    AP_ATTRIBUTE.stylename,
    AP_BASIC.style,
    AP_ATTRIBUTE.color,
    AP_ATTRIBUTE.size,
    AP_BASIC.ap_sizesequence_id,
    M_TRANSACTION.movementdate,
    M_PRODUCTPRICE.pricelist,
    M_INOUT.M_INOUT_ID,
    M_INOUT.DOCUMENTNO,
    C_BPARTNER.VALUE
ORDER BY
    M_TRANSACTION.movementdate,
    M_INOUT.M_INOUT_ID,
    style,
    color,
    size
```

There are 2,962,657 rows in `M_TRANSACTION`.
pk: m_transaction_id
index: m_product_id

There are 106,380 rows in `AP_ATTRIBUTE`.
pk: AP_ATTRIBUTE_id
no index

There are 6,128 rows in `AP_BASIC`.
pk: AP_BASIC_id
no index

There are 223,917 rows in `M_PRODUCTPRICE`.
index: (m_pricelist_version_id, m_product_id)

There are 2,000,329 rows in `M_INOUTLINE`.
pk: m_inoutline_id
index: m_product_id, m_inout_id

There are 45,919 rows in `M_INOUT`.
pk: m_inout_id
index: m_inout_id

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` reveals this plan (also at [explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com/s/ROV)):

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=201073.74..201073.78 rows=1 width=138) (actual time=944255.849..944256.284 rows=517 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=201073.74..201073.74 rows=1 width=138) (actual time=944255.828..944255.859 rows=517 loops=1)
        Sort Key: m_transaction.movementdate, m_inout.m_inout_id, ap_basic.style, ap_attribute.color, ap_attribute.size, ap_attribute.stylename, ap_basic.ap_sizesequence_id, m_productprice.pricelist, m_inout.documentno, c_bpartner.value
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 162kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..201073.73 rows=1 width=138) (actual time=272067.456..944244.793 rows=517 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..201066.14 rows=1 width=146) (actual time=272067.433..944239.495 rows=517 loops=1)
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..201058.34 rows=1 width=107) (actual time=13.225..943784.425 rows=28860 loops=1)
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join (cost=0.00..201049.06 rows=1 width=107) (actual time=13.197..940249.631 rows=28860 loops=1)
                                ->  Nested Loop Left Join (cost=0.00..201040.64 rows=1 width=136) (actual time=13.122..938969.396 rows=28860 loops=1)
                                      ->  Nested Loop (cost=0.00..201032.88 rows=1 width=130) (actual time=13.086..938463.010 rows=28860 loops=1)
                                            Join Filter: ((m_transaction.m_product_id)::text = (ap_attribute.m_product_id)::text)
                                            ->  Seq Scan on m_transaction  (cost=0.00..188132.06 rows=1 width=78) (actual time=0.015..932.400 rows=28936 loops=1)
                                                  Filter: ((m_inoutline_id IS NOT NULL) AND ((ad_client_id)::text = ANY ('{0,FF80818129E99DC80129E9AD546A0708}'::text[])) AND (movementdate >= '2012-12-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (movementdate < '2013-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((ad_org_id)::text = ANY ('{44523886B0E0423584BB0E87133F3EE4,4510F92E007E48B28EE6CEB088A78348,0}'::text[])))
                                            ->  Seq Scan on ap_attribute  (cost=0.00..11820.75 rows=86405 width=85) (actual time=0.001..20.121 rows=86645 loops=28936)
                                                  Filter: (isactive = 'Y'::bpchar)
                                      ->  Index Scan using ap_bs_key on ap_basic  (cost=0.00..7.76 rows=1 width=72) (actual time=0.013..0.014 rows=1 loops=28860)
                                            Index Cond: ((ap_basic_id)::text = (ap_attribute.ap_basic_id)::text)
                                ->  Index Scan using m_productprice_pricelist_ve_un on m_productprice  (cost=0.00..8.40 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.042..0.042 rows=1 loops=28860)
                                      Index Cond: (((m_pricelist_version_id)::text = '69CBAFD24AB24E3CB9B9A44E282D62EC'::text) AND ((m_transaction.m_product_id)::text = (m_product_id)::text))
                          ->  Index Scan using m_inoutline_key on m_inoutline  (cost=0.00..9.27 rows=1 width=66) (actual time=0.120..0.120 rows=1 loops=28860)
                                Index Cond: ((m_inoutline_id)::text = (m_transaction.m_inoutline_id)::text)
                    ->  Index Scan using m_inout_key on m_inout (cost=0.00..7.79 rows=1 width=72) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=28860)
                          Index Cond: ((m_inout_id)::text = (m_inoutline.m_inout_id)::text)
                          Filter: (((m_warehouse_id)::text = '50657AE0F49A421A9F10154C8632A726'::text) AND (issotrx = 'N'::bpchar))
              ->  Index Scan using c_bpartner_key on c_bpartner (cost=0.00..7.57 rows=1 width=56) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=1 loops=517)
                    Index Cond: ((c_bpartner_id)::text = (m_inout.c_bpartner_id)::text)
```

Total runtime: 944,256.536 ms

27 資料列

Total runtime: 944,319.072 ms

How can I improve the query's performance?

Comment: Your query is really hard to read... can you clean it up a bit?

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Comment: You could just say a little over 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I reformatted, removed noise and cruft, added table aliases and converted to explicit ANSI join syntax, among other things:

```
SELECT
    a.stylename,
    b.style,
    a.color,
    a.size,
    b.ap_sizesequence_id,
    t.movementdate,
    SUM(t.movementqty) AS movementqty,
    COALESCE(p.pricelist, 999999) AS pricelist,
    i.m_inout_id,
    i.documentno,
    c.value as bpname,
    '' as m_movementline_id,
    '' as movement,
    '' as movement_description,
    '' as m_inventory_id,
    '' as m_movement_id,
    '' as m_productionplan_id,
    '' as production_plan
FROM   M_TRANSACTION       t
JOIN   AP_ATTRIBUTE        a ON a.m_product_id = t.m_product_id
JOIN   M_INOUTLINE         l ON l.m_inoutline_id = t.m_inoutline_id
JOIN   M_INOUT             i ON i.m_inout_id = l.m_inout_id
JOIN   C_BPARTNER          c ON c.c_bpartner_id = i.c_bpartner_id
LEFT   JOIN AP_BASIC       b ON b.ap_basic_id = a.ap_basic_id
LEFT   JOIN M_PRODUCTPRICE p ON p.m_product_id = t.m_product_id
            AND p.m_pricelist_version_id = '69CBAFD24AB24E3CB9B9A44E282D62EC'
WHERE  t.ad_client_id = ANY(
       '{FF80818129E99DC80129E9AD546A0708
        ,0}')
AND    t.ad_org_id = ANY(
       '{44523886B0E0423584BB0E87133F3EE4
        ,4510F92E007E48B28EE6CEB088A78348
        ,0}')
AND    t.movementdate >= '2012-12-01 0:0'::timestamp
AND    t.movementdate <  '2013-01-01 0:0'::timestamp
AND    i.m_warehouse_id = '50657AE0F49A421A9F10154C8632A726'
AND    i.issotrx = 'N'
AND    a.isactive = 'Y'
GROUP BY
    a.stylename,
    a.color,
    a.size,
    b.style,
    b.ap_sizesequence_id,
    t.movementdate,
    p.pricelist,
    i.m_inout_id,
    c.value
ORDER BY
    t.movementdate,
    i.m_inout_id,
    b.style,
    a.color,
    a.size
```

#### Major points

- Added **table aliases** to make the monster easier to read.
- Removed a couple of redundant **column aliases** like `b.ap_sizesequence_id AS apsizesequenceid`
- Converted to **lower case** where mixed case identifiers are just noise.
- Transformed your joins to **ANSI joins** with join conditions. Makes complex queries easier to read and debug.
- Removed `i.documentno` from the `GROUP BY` clause. I Postgres 9.1 the PK column `i.m_inout_id` already covers the whole table. There may be more redundant columns. Check for yourself.
- `t.m_inoutline_id IS NOT NULL` was redundant. Covered by: 
  `JOIN   M_INOUTLINE l ON l.m_inoutline_id = t.m_inoutline_id`
- `= ANY()` is slightly faster than `IN()`
- `AND a.isactive = 'Y'` force-converts the `LEFT JOIN AP_ATTRIBUTE` to a regular `JOIN`.
- `t.movementdate` is a `timestamp` (as EXPLAIN output tells me). Simplified expression accordingly.
- `i.issotrx` and `a.isactive` should most probably be of type **`boolean`** instead of `character` (`bpchar`). (Can't do anything about *that*)

#### Indexes

- You need **at least** an **index** on `M_TRANSACTION.movementdate`:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX m_transaction_movementdate_idx
  ON m_transaction(movementdate)
  ```

  Or possibly a [**multicolumn index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) like:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX m_transaction_movementdate_idx
  ON m_transaction(ad_client_id, ad_org_id, movementdate)
  ```

  Depends on your actual data distribution and other circumstances.
- You need an index on `AP_ATTRIBUTE.m_product_id`:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ap_attribute_m_product_id_idx
  ON ap_attribute (m_product_id)
  ```

  Maybe even better a **partial index**:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ap_attribute_m_product_id_idx
  ON ap_attribute (m_product_id)
  WHERE isactive = 'Y'
  ```

  I posted lots of answers concerning partial indexes. [Try a search here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:939860%20%22partial%20index%22&submit=search).
- Another index may help:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX m_inout_m_warehouse_id_idx ON m_inout (m_warehouse_id)
  ```

  Again, potentially partial with

  ```
  ...
  WHERE issotrx = 'N'
  ```